# WSO2- how to get custom user profile claim from Identity server with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

In my requirement, i have users in the IS. And I need to log into other applications by entering his user name and password. then the application should call the service provider which is defined inside IS and check whether the person who is trying to log into the application is actually authenticated user, then user name, email and user permissions also should be sent to the application as the response from the service provider. 
I'm using OAuth2. Using Is 5.1.0. 
Can anyone please guide me how to implement this
Can I check it with rest client tool like postman also?